# Neo4j 3.1.4: Can't up casual cluster while cores defined on three different hosts

Tags: neo4j

I try to form and run causal cluster on three different hosts and it doesn't work: servers can't connect with each other. So, any help/any comment will be appreciated.`

```
    **neo4jlog:**

 ======== Neo4j 3.1.4 ========

INFO  Starting...

INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.

INFO  Initiating metrics...

INFO  My connection info: [
    Discovery:   listen=172.16.140.10:5000, advertised=localhost:5000,

    Transaction: listen=127.0.0.1:6000, advertised=localhost:6000, 

    Raft:        listen=127.0.0.1:7000, advertised=localhost:7000, 

    Client Connector Addresses:

        bolt://localhost:7687,

        http://localhost:7474,

        https://localhost:6476]

 INFO  Discovering cluster with initial members: [
172.16.140.10:5000, 
172.16.140.11:5001, 
10.4.4.8:5000
]
INFO  Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing...

after some minutes:

ERROR Failed to start Neo4j...

neo4j.conf(1):


dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true

dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

dbms.connector.http.enabled=true

dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:6476

causal_clustering.expected_core_cluster_size=3
causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members=
172.16.140.10:5000,
172.16.140.11:5001,
10.4.4.8:5000

causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address=172.16.140.10:5000
causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address=127.0.0.1:6000
causal_clustering.raft_listen_address=127.0.0.1:7000

other things are default

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

neo4j.conf (2):

dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7689

dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:6476


dbms.mode=CORE
causal_clustering.expected_core_cluster_size=3
causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members=172.16.140.10:5000,172.16.140.11:5001,10.4.4.8:5000
causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address=172.16.140.11:5001
causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address=127.0.0.1:6000
causal_clustering.raft_listen_address=127.0.0.1:7000

other things are default
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    neo4j.conf(3)

    dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
   dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687

dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7474

dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473

dbms.mode=CORE
causal_clustering.expected_core_cluster_size=3
causal_clustering.initial_discovery_members=172.16.140.10:5000,172.16.140.11:5001,10.4.4.8:5000
causal_clustering.discovery_listen_address=10.4.4.8:5000
causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address=127.0.0.1:6000
causal_clustering.raft_listen_address=127.0.0.1:7000

other things are default
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

When I started servers, I checked 
netstat -apn on each station:
I see that port 5000 is open and LISTEN for each of them.

I even test if port 5000 for each one of them is reachable by another one:

cat < /dev/tcp/172.16.140.11/5000 from 172.16.140.10 and from 10.4.4.8

cat < /dev/tcp/172.16.140.10/5000 from 172.16.140.11 and from 10.4.4.8

cat < /dev/tcp/10.4.4.8/5000 from 172.16.140.10 and from 172.16.140.11`
```

and it's  OK : ports are up and reachable.
Anyway, cluster can't up.
System:
Neo4j 3.1.4; Centos 7

Thanks you.

Comment: The problem was solved (discovery bug was fixed) in version 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reach the 6000 and 7000 ports from other machines too.
You should set the real ip address in the transaction_listen_address and raft_listen_address properties. Or use 0.0.0.0
If you listeners are on the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), then the other cluster members can not reach it.

Comment: tried both 0.0.0.0 and concrete ip address.For two of the servers got an exeption: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hazelcast CANNOT start on this node. No matching network interface found.
Interface matching must be either disabled or updated in the hazelcast.xml config file.at com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.pickInterfaceAddress(DefaultAddressPicker.java:196)

Comment: whole stack trace:Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hazelcast CANNOT start on this node. No matching network interface found.
Interface matching must be either disabled or updated in the hazelcast.xml config file.
 at com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker.pickInterfaceAddress(DefaultAddressPicker.java:196)
 at ....org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:433)

Comment: You should check that the 6000 and 7000 ports are not in use. Sometimes port 6000 is taken by X window. You should check these ports like you did with 5000. I would try with 6001 and 7001, you never know.
And you can try like this without the ip address:
causal_clustering.transaction_listen_address=:6000

Comment: Tried =:6000, tried 6001,7001... The same. Checked these ports by netstat -apn, - they don't  appear in a list...  does it mean they are closed, aren't they?  I supposed they should be open during a process starting neo4j (neo4j start).So,does it mean that something wrong with neo4j.conf?

Comment: looks like a neo4j bug: ports 6000 and 7000 (for raft and transactions accordingly) should be open for listening during neo4j start (like port 5000), but they are not. I suppose it causes servers don't speak with each other.